# Optional map and orElse has to return same type

Tags: java, null, option-type

I have this code:

```
Object s = ofNullable(resp).map(ResponseEntity::getBody).orElse(ex.getMessage());
ResponseEntity::getBody returns Object and ex.getMessage returns String
```

I get a compiler error :

```
The method orElse(capture#10-of ?) in the type Optional<capture#10-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

But I can write this without optional and it works fine:

```
Object s = resp != null ? resp.getBody() : ex.getMessage();
```

Comment: You don't need optionals here. Just keep your iterative code.

Comment: "obj1::get1 returns Object" Are you sure? It looks like it returns `capture#10-of ?`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think you're right, wonder what the error is with `s = (resp != null) ? obj1.get1() : ex.getMessage();`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `obj1.get1(resp)`, presumably. With that, I don't see that there'd be an error.

Comment: You could do it in two statements: `Optional<Object> opt = ofNullable(resp).map(obj1::get1); Object s = opt.orElse(msg);`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from how Java does type inference.

Method references (and lambdas) are *polyexpressions*. This means that the same expression can have a different type, depending on where it is used.

So, your polyexpression:

```
ofNullable(resp).map(obj1::get1)
```

has *some* type.

If you were to use it in an assignment context:

```
Optional<Object> opt1 = ofNullable(resp).map(obj1::get1);
Optional<?> opt2      = ofNullable(resp).map(obj1::get1);
```

then these would both be fine, since the type inference constraints allow the type parameter of the optional to match the type parameter of the variable.

However, if you use the expression as a receiver of another method invocation:

```
ofNullable(resp).map(obj1::get1).orElse(...)
```

then Java infers the type of the `ofNullable(...).map(...)` first (it's no longer a polyexpression), and then proceeds to the `orElse`.

Clearly, `obj1.get1(resp)` isn't returning an `Object` as you claim, but rather some wildcard type. This is the inferred type of the optional: `Optional<some wildcard>`. The parameter of `orElse` then has to be of type `some wildcard` too; the only possible value for that is `null`.

There are a number of ways around it:

- You could explicitly assign the result of `ofNullable(...).map(...)` to a variable of type `Optional<Object>`, then invoke the `orElse` on the variable;
- You could cast to `Optional<Object>`:

  ```
  ((Optional<Object>) ofNullable(...).map(...)).orElse(...)
  ```
- You can explicitly map to Object:

  ```
  ofNullable(...).map(...).map(Object.class::cast)
  ```
- You could use a lambda instead, and cast the result to `Object`:

  ```
  ofNullable(...).map(r -> (Object) ...).orElse(...)
  ```

Or you could just keep it simple, and not try to use `Optional`:

```
Object s = (resp != null) ? obj1.get(resp) : ex.getMessage();
```

Comment: The simplest is to replace `.map(obj1::get1)` with `.<Object>map(obj1::get1)`…